# Prompt msgbox when a column of the query result is not empty

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query called `Search_Tool` which output one of the record from the table that is searched by `Serial Number`. The Criteria of the `Serial Number` is the one of the `txtbox.value` in the `form`. The query is then displayed on a `List Box`. The query will be activated upon pressing a `button`. However i need a msgbox prompt when one of the column displayed in the query is filled.

So when I input 123456789 into the text box and press search, it should prompt a msgbox when it detects that the `Date` is not empty.

How can I make this msgbox happen?

I have made another post for clearer understanding: [The blank column of the particular List Box based on query is not recognized as either empty or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384657/the-blank-column-of-the-particular-list-box-based-on-query-is-not-recognized-as)

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim check As String
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "xxxxx_Search"
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "xxxxx_Search"
    SearchList.Requery

    If SearchList.ListCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No records found.")
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "xxxxx_Unload"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Not IsNull("End_Date", "xxxxx_Search") Then
        MsgBox ("The Unload data for this Serial Number have been filled.")
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "xxxxx_Unload"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

```
SELECT xxxxx.Serial_Number, xxxxx.End_Date, xxxxx.End_Time, xxxxx.End_System_Time, xxxxx.End_Operator, xxxxx.Success, V.End_Remarks
FROM xxxxx
WHERE (((xxxxx.Serial_Number)=[Forms]![xxxxx_Unload]![txtSearch]));
```

Comment: Now the issue is that the listbox in linked to the query where the query have 7 columns. so a particular record have column that is empty and when it is displayed on the listbox is shown as empty. But when i try to check if that column `is not null` or `is not empty`, it should be false and prompt a msgbox `it is empty`. However it turns out to be true even though it is empty and prompted a msgbox  `it is filled`. I suspect that listbox does not recognize those blank query result column as empty or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must address the control and its value, not its name:

```
ElseIf Not IsNull(Me![End_Date].Value) Then
```

For a listbox:

```
ElseIf Nz(Me!SearchList.Column(1)) <> "" Then
```

Comment: So this statement means if the end_date is not empty it will return a true?

Comment: Yes. Check it out.

Comment: it say microsoft access can't find the field 'End_Date' referred to in your expression. Is it cause i did not link my form to a record source?

Comment: i solve the issue by using listbox.column() as the listbox is link to the query


    If Not IsNull(SearchList.Column(1)) Then
        MsgBox ("The Unload data for this Serial Number have been filled.")
        DoCmd.Close
        DoCmd.OpenForm "xxxxx_Unload"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Comment: but now even though the listbox.column() is empty, it will prompt the msgbox, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the listbox column holds a zero-length string. See edited answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have this function in my projects and use it instead of IsNull() - it is more flexible.

```
Public Function IsEmptyOrNull(strValue As Variant) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_
    If Trim(strValue) = vbNullString Or isnull(strValue) Then
        IsEmptyOrNull = True
    End If
Err_:
End Function
```